# How do I specify which compiler toolchain Yocto uses to build images?

Tags: cross-compiling, yocto, external, toolchain, linaro

For example, how could I get my image to be compiled using:

`gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux`?

What does `core-image-sato` has to do with the toolchains (they supply with Yocto)?
I don't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `local.conf` file, specify the path of your toolchain in your system.

```
EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN = "/home/manjunath/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2014.11-20121123_linux"
```

In your original toolchain distro add `toolchain-external-linaro.inc`

More [specifically](http://git://git.linaro.org/openembedded/meta-linaro.git)

you get a directory named `meta-linaro-toolchain`. You may copy complete or

Add `.inc` to your distribution (sources/poky/meta-yocto/conf/distro/  in my case).

Try now ...